# Не получается записать в переменную значение конкатенации этой переменной и другого поля

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Присваиваю переменной значение и записываю в неё новое значение, которое состоит из текущего значения + значение необходимого поля.

Результатом выполнения запроса является первая буква имени поля, а не старое значение переменной @str плюс <имя нужного поля>, как хотелось бы.

Если данные записывать в дополнительную переменную, а не в эту же, то работает аналогично.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR=
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        COLUMN_NAME
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 2
            COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1'
        ORDER BY
            ORDINAL_POSITION
    ) AS a
    ORDER BY
        COLUMN_NAME
);

SET @str = @str+
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1'
);

SELECT
    @str AS FIELDS;
```

Comment: Задайте длину переменной при объявлении `declare @str as varchar(100)`

Comment: `declare @str as varchar` эквивалентно `declare @str as varchar(1)`. Потому и остается только первая буква.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте длину переменной, например `VARCHAR(max)` или любую другую длину, которой вам достаточно. `VARCHAR = VARCHAR (1)`